# Starting aar activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have made an android archive (.aar) which has two activities. I want to use those in another app.

I was able to call the functions of aar by using the aar MainActivity class but I am unable to call upon the activity using startActivity() which I need as the activity layout is not loading right now.

Comment: Don't think this would work with AAR; and if then through reflection, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611149/how-to-start-an-activity-in-a-dynamic-feature-module).

Comment: Any errors? If you have any error logs, please [edit] the question and post it here. And also if possible, screenshots from the Android device you can post.