# Third party library of dynamic feature module cannot access resources

Tags: android, android-library, dynamic-feature-module

I have a application which has a dynamic feature module. In dynamic feature module, there is a form with images, input fields and also it has a buttton which access another third-party library.

Third-party library has a activity and fragment. While opening fragment inside activity, I am receiving below error, although there is container in activity's layout:

> No view found for id 0x7f080053 (com.app.sample:id/container) for fragment SampleFragment{eed53f7 (5e4c0693-09a2-4725-a6de-1df49dd818f0) id=0x7f080053}

When accessing drawables in this third-party library, getting below error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field ic_back of type I in class Lcom.third.library/R$drawable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.third.library.R$drawable' appears in /data/app/com.app.sample-QtC8XuamC1fHEVU4FUpWaA==/split_thirdparty.apk)

It is fine when I use this library in a application without dynamic feature module.
[image]

Comment: Is the 3rd party library an open library (e.g. available on github) , so we can reproduce? And is it only used within the `dynamic-feature-module1` or also in the `App1` module or on other modules on the level of the `dynamic-feature-module1`?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might be worth reading, because error messages without the least code are rather abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when `SplitCompat.installActivity(this)` isn't called in `Activity2`, this won't work. While not having the source code, you'd have to extract the package and re-package it properly, because the `Activity2` (or even the whole library package) likely isn't compatible with DFM.

> After you enable SplitCompat for your base app, **you need to enable SplitCompat for each activity** that your app downloads in a dynamic feature module.

Here's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58617189/549372) of mine, which demonstrates access through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Delivery is relatively new feature so it has a lot of limitations. One of those limitations it that you cannot access code and resources of a Dynamic Module in a conventional way, thus it cannot be a dependency for other modules. Currently you can access Dynamic Module via reflection and having dynamic features defined through public interfaces in a common library module and loading their actual implementations (located in the dynamic feature modules) at runtime with a [`ServiceLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader). It has its performance downsides. They can be minimized with R8 using [`ServiceLoaderRewriter`](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/b027e3c0b123bd4a9397ff210e40293c1381d1a8/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/ir/optimize/ServiceLoaderRewriter.java#35) but not completely removed.

While using reflection is very bug prone we can minimize it either with [`@AutoService`](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) — `AutoService` is an annotation processor that will scan the project for classes annotated with `@AutoService`, for any class it finds it will automatically generate a service definition file for it.

Here is small example of how it is done

```
// All feature definitions extend this interface, T is the dependencies that the feature requires
interface Feature<T> {
    fun getMainScreen(): Fragment
    fun getLaunchIntent(context: Context): Intent
    fun inject(dependencies: T)
}

interface VideoFeature : Feature<VideoFeature.Dependencies> {
    interface Dependencies {
        val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
        val context: Context
        val handler: Handler
        val backgroundDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    }
}

internal var videoComponent: VideoComponent? = null
    private set

@AutoService(VideoFeature::class)
class VideoFeatureImpl : VideoFeature {
    override fun getLaunchIntent(context: Context): Intent = Intent(context, VideoActivity::class.java)

    override fun getMainScreen(): Fragment = createVideoFragment()

    override fun inject(dependencies: VideoFeature.Dependencies) {
        if (videoComponent != null) {
            return
        }

        videoComponent = DaggerVideoComponent.factory()
                .create(dependencies, this)
    }
}
```

And to actually access code of Dynamic Feature use

```
inline fun <reified T : Feature<D>, D> FeatureManager.getFeature(
        dependencies: D
): T? {
    return if (isFeatureInstalled<T>()) {
        val serviceIterator = ServiceLoader.load(
                T::class.java,
                T::class.java.classLoader
        ).iterator()

        if (serviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            val feature = serviceIterator.next()
            feature.apply { inject(dependencies) }
        } else {
            null
        }
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/navigation-with-dynamic-feature-modules-48ee7645488). Also there a lot more info there so I would recommend you to check it.

Generally I just would not recommend to use Dynamic Feature as dependency and plan your app architecture accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the resources, this code part can be usage

`R.id.settings` would be:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("settings", "id", "com.library.package");
```