# Android-Espresso test doesn't run after Android Studio upgrade from 3.5.1 to 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

After I did an upgrade from Android Studio 3.5.1 to 4.0, I can't run any Espresso test, giving me following exception on the run window:

```
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Running Instrumented Tests for Dynamic Features is currently not supported on API < 21.
```

Comment: Possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611149/how-to-start-an-activity-in-a-dynamic-feature-module

Comment: BTW, the app it self is building and running without any issue, the exception is only thrown when an Espresso test cases is being run

Comment: Once down graded from 4.0 to 3.6.3 all test are working as expected. AS version 4.0 was not working for me, all kind of test (unit test, instrumentation test and Espresso test) were failing due to the the same exception above.

Comment: There might be something else wrong; my tests work as always (at least without DFM). DFM seems to be setup incorrectly, because this is exactly what the error message hints for. Or there is indeed a bug with testing DFM. Have you tried the above workaround for testing DFM?

Comment: Had the same issue too, glad to say it's been fixed in AS 4.0.1